# Automatic calling of prestashop module method on fixed interval, to update database values

Tags: prestashop

I am developing a Prestashop backend module without any hooks. I want to call a method included in module on fixed interval (interval can be set in module configuration) to update some database values. Is this possible in Prestashop? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cron job to call a url, or use a module for this. I've used [this module](http://addons.prestashop.com/en/administration-tools-prestashop-modules/671-crontab-for-prestashop.html) in the past, works well.

Comment: So will there be any problem regarding to permission to edit or execute commands using cron job? What linux user's cron job file should I use for this? It is a standalone module which will be distributed to my different clients, so I don't have any control over deployed machine's environment.
Also crontab for prestashop module is not a solution for me as I am developing a standalone module without any third party module dependency.